# returning a number to its double value

Tags: c#, numbers

I'm creating a program to evaluate the number inputted for example I inputted 5 the function should be able to return the number which means:

```
5  => 500   
4  => 400  
6  => 600 
10 => 1000 and so on.
```

This is what I've done so far.

```
public int NumberEval(int theNumber)
{
    int theResult = 0;
    switch (theNumber)
    {
        case 0:
            theResult = 1;
            break;
        case 1:
            theResult = 1;
            break;
        case 2:
            theResult = 200;
            break;
        case 3:
            theResult = 300;
            break;
        case 4:
            theResult = 400;
            break;
        case 5:
            theResult = 500;
            break;
        case 6:
            theResult = 600;
            break;
        case 7:
            theResult = 700;
            break;
        case 8:
            theResult = 800;
            break;
        case 9:
            theResult = 900;
            break;
        case 10:
            theResult = 1000;
            break;
        case 11:
            theResult = 1100;
            break;
        case 12:
            theResult = 1200;
            break;
        case 13:
            theResult = 1300;
            break;
        case 14:
            theResult = 1400;
            break;
        case 15:
            theResult = 1500;
            break;
        case 16:
            theResult = 1600;
            break;
        case 17:
            theResult = 1700;
            break;
        case 18:
            theResult = 1800;
            break;
        case 19:
            theResult = 1900;
            break;
        case 20:
            theResult = 2000;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return theResult;
}
```

My problem is that what if I enter 50 then it should be 5000. Is there a way to shortcut this method because I don't want to manually encode every item in the switch statement? Or even a mathematical equation for this?

Comment: Multiply by 100?

Comment: ... except if `theNumber == 1` or `== 0`, in which case just return 1 (unless that was a typo in your question?). For future reference, the first question you should ask yourself is "how did I know what I want to return?" That is, what made you think that if `theNumber == 9` you should return 900? If you'd done that and came up with "because 9 * 100 = 900", that would give you a hint as to how to solve this without hard-coding every answer.

Comment: do you have to use a switch?

Comment: and some overflowing values would need carry int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not a simple multiplication with `100` like the following:

```
public int NumberEval(int theNumber)
{
    if(theNumber == 0 || theNumber == 1)
       return 1;
    else
       return theNumber * 100;
}
```

Here is a [working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tiuT7p) for you. You can simplify the statements like this:

```
return theNumber == 0 || theNumber == 1 ? 1 : theNumber * 100;
```

Comment: thank you very much sir, this is what i'm looking for

Answer (score 3):

Isn't this a pattern with input*100? I think you could write a method accept the input and multi it by 100. But there is something need to be care about is the  precision truncation while the input is large enough to overflow the integer precision.

Comment: hello thank you for your tip but how can i avoid it. im new to programming so i dont really much know about integer precision.